# Okta PySAML2 Example App: IP-Initiated Works but SP-Initiated Fails

Tags: python, saml-2.0, okta

I followed Okta's [Setting up a SAML Application in Okta](http://developer.okta.com/docs/examples/setting_up_a_saml_application_in_okta.html) document, including the adjustments for the FirstName and LastName attributes discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932899/saml2-service-provider-in-python), and followed the Okta "PySAML2" page (not enough reputation for a third link) to run a Flask app that authenticates using Okta.

When running the Flask app (with the appropriate setting change for the 'example-okta-com' URL), the IdP-initiated flow works, so I can get to the example app from Okta, but if I try to click the 'example-okta-com' link within the app, which points to http://localhost:5000/saml/login/example-okta-com, then I get redirected to an error page on the subdomain of oktapreview.com for my test app containing the following stack trace:

```
Error: user_exception

Error parsing XML in SAML request
 com.saasure.application.factory.AppUserException: Error parsing XML in SAML request
    at com.saasure.application.generic.services.impl.OutboundSAMLServiceImpl.isForceAuthn(OutboundSAMLServiceImpl.java:351)
    at com.saasure.application.generic.ui.controller.sso.SAMLForceAuthnController.requiresForceAuthn(SAMLForceAuthnController.java:137)
    at com.saasure.application.generic.ui.controller.sso.DefaultSAMLController.handleSAML20AuthnRequestForSpecificInstance(DefaultSAMLController.java:97)
    at com.saasure.application.generic.ui.controller.sso.DefaultSAMLController.handleSAML20AuthnRequestForSpecificInstance(DefaultSAMLController.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1246.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:685)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.saasure.framework.web.filter.ServletExceptionFilter.doFilterInternal(ServletExceptionFilter.java:30)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.saasure.framework.web.filter.GzipFilter.doFilterInternal(GzipFilter.java:26)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.saasure.framework.web.filter.HeadToGetFilter.doFilterInternal(HeadToGetFilter.java:31)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at nl.remcojansen.tomcatlogging.JuliAccessLogValve.invoke(JuliAccessLogValve.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:889)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:2274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.opensaml.xml.parse.XMLParserException: Invalid XML
    at org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool.parse(BasicParserPool.java:218)
    at com.saasure.framework.security.saml.impl.BaseSAMLBuilder.unmarshallXml(BaseSAMLBuilder.java:269)
    at com.saasure.framework.security.saml.impl.BaseSAMLBuilder.unmarshallXml(BaseSAMLBuilder.java:277)
    at com.saasure.framework.security.saml.impl.SAML20IdentityProviderImpl.unmarshallRequest(SAML20IdentityProviderImpl.java:337)
    at com.saasure.framework.security.saml.impl.SAML20IdentityProviderImpl.isForceAuthn(SAML20IdentityProviderImpl.java:320)
    at com.saasure.application.generic.services.impl.OutboundSAMLServiceImpl.isForceAuthn(OutboundSAMLServiceImpl.java:347)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool$DocumentBuilderProxy.parse(BasicParserPool.java:671)
    at org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool.parse(BasicParserPool.java:215)
    ... 58 more
```

The only change I made to the example app is to change the `metadata_url_for` dict so that it has an 'example-okta-com' key with the value being the metadata URL from step 10 of the Okta doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application in Okta needs to be configured to accept compressed SAML AuthN requests.

I apologize, I should have put this in the documentation. I'll do that shortly.

In the meantime, you will want to set "Request Compression" to "Compressed" in the Okta application you set up. Here is what that will look like:

[image: Image of the "Edit SAML Integration" page in Okta]

Comment: Thanks, Joël. That was it. And thanks for the great docs and the example app. I don't have reputation so can't vote up your answer or accept it.

Comment: @JoeKnecht you don't need reputation to mark answers as correct.