# Setup Azure Active Directory SAML using Python

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I have Setup Azure Active Directory with SAML2.0 SSO Setup for my local flask application from Portal.

can someone suggest any library or article with the example on how to implement SAML based authentication on python flask application?

I have checked a few libraries but not able to found out how to set up the API and how to configure using python.

Comment: I have tried python-saml library but not able to connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can someone suggest any library or article with the example on how to implement SAML based authentication on python flask application?

This [guide](https://developer.okta.com/code/python/pysaml2/) describes how to use PySAML2 to add support for Okta (via SAML) to applications written in Python. And refer to the [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932899/saml-2-0-service-provider-in-python) for implementing a SAML SP in Python/Flask.

Also, you can use the open source library provided and supported by OneLogin, refer to this [article](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml).