# Azure SAML Authentication in Flask Web App

Tags: python-3.x, flask, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I'm trying to configure a SAML Authentication with Azure in a Flask web service.
Is the first time I'm doing this and I'm bit lost.

I'm trying to use the 'SAML_METADA_URL' provided in AZURE but I don't know what to configure in python side.
In Azure seems to be all setup, the app was added, have the client ID and CLIENT SECRET, ETC.

Anyone knows a good and specific tutorial for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the [SAML-enabled Python application guide](https://developer.okta.com/code/python/pysaml2/), which explains how to use PySAML2 to add Okta support (via SAML) to an application written in Python, And refer to the [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932899/saml-2-0-service-provider-in-python) for implementing a SAML SP in Python/Flask.

In addition, OneLogin also provides a SAML Python toolkit, I believe it will also be helpful to you [here](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml).

Comment: Thanks for you reply Carl Zhao. 
I'm aware of one login examples but I'm trying to use Azure AD specifically.
Anyway, thks for the tips